# Can you scale Cassandra as much as you want?

Tags: cassandra

Say serving from 1000 users a day to a billion users a day as long as you are horizontally scaling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes. You can scale to as many nodes as you want.

I've worked on several clusters with 100-300 nodes. A handful that were above 700-800 nodes. And a few times, on clusters with just above 1200 nodes.

I know of companies who run workloads on larger clusters although I haven't worked on those.

We regularly run regression testing on 1000-node clusters. Once you get to about 150-200 nodes, you're in petabyte territory. That's pretty serious and you'd be in an elite circle of internet giants. Cheers!